# Using Perl regex to match files of a certain extension, but not if there are additional extensions

Tags: regex, perl

I have a perl script that needs to process some files with a certain extension, say..

.example

I just want files with this extension, however, in the directory that i need to run the current script in there are other files that are needed for the "process" to run, but not this particular script, say..

.example.data

I just want to process .example and avoid .example.data is there a perl regex for this solution?

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, just look for exactly the end.

```
$file =~ m/\.example$/
```

That will not match `.example.data`

Answer (score 2):

Use `glob()` function to catch all the files with extension `.example`

```
my @example_files = glob("*.example");
```

If you wish to add a directory:

```
my @example_files = glob("/var/tmp/*.example");
```